How can I speed up my training time for a python-chess bot using ppo?
I am attempting to build a chess bot which learns using Proximal Policy Optimization. I am currently using the python-chess library (https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) as the environment where my agent plays games against itself and learns. The issue I am facing is extremely slow games for training. With a move limit of 200 per game, my bot can play 1 game against itself in about 1 second. This 1 second also includes the PPO part of the training which takes on average 0.01 seconds with a GPU.
I am using PyTorch, so I have already moved all tensors to the GPU. I have not found any other ways beyond this to speed up the execution time.
I would like to get the execution time down for playing the games to around 0.5 or less seconds per game, but I haven't been able to find a way to accomplish this.
I would greatly appreciate the feedback and help if anyone knows of a possible solution.

You can use GPU acceleration. If you have an NVIDIA GPU, use GPU acceleration python libraries. This is how I train all of my AI models, whether chess related or just fun projects.

Could you specifically mention how to approach this solution through a code snippet or preferably more resources
